# Get Svg from openweatherapi

Tags: typescript, svg, next.js, openweathermap

Currently I'm working on a weather app project in nextjs with openweathermap API. From the API i get icons which i can combine with this URL:
https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/ to get the icons.

Here is an example:

```js
<img
   src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ICON_URL}${dayItem[0]?.weather[0]?.icon}@2x.png`}
/>
```

In this code the process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ICON_URL is the URL. And the icon is from the API response.

The problem is that these are just png's and have really bad quality when I make them bigger. So I just wanted to ask if there is a possibility to get svgs from the openweathermap icons so that i can display them bigger without loss of quality.

On the openweatherapi I was looking for svgs. Unfortunately I havn't found any. Maybe i can get svgs from the description of the weather from other svg provider?